# Given that the team@ email addresses are publicly exposed, who is responsible for them on the team?

Tags: support, email, stack-exchange-team

Given that the team@ email addresses are publicly exposed, who is responsible for them on the team?

Who should we expect to be handling the email addresses, and what's the usual turnaround time if we don't get a response?

And if we don't get a response, at what point should we send another message (and to what address) to handle that situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently these emails are handled by the community team. The turnaround time ... varies, but we try to get back to everyone within 48 hours.

We encourage everyone to use the new [/help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) system instead, though, since it should cover most common scenarios we're typically emailed about. It is available from the bottom of every page on every site via the "contact us" link.